# Scratched/Etched onto wood look

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

What would be the best way to create an effect of "keying" someones name into a piece of wood in photoshop? I've used a hard 2px brush with a tan color and it looks good. Just not believeable. What do I need for that "wow" factor... to really make it look legitimate?

Kinda sorta like this:

[image]

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=photoshop+tutorial+etched+into+wood

Comment: Yeah, I've seen those tutorials, but they look "carved" in. I am looking for something gritty and "scratched" into wood.

Comment: Always good to find a photo reference. Or make one yourself.

Comment: In your photo I see rough lines, hand drawn, bark texture, cut marks, cast shadows, a gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help you in the right direction. I put together a little tutorial for you.
http://fariidayasin.tumblr.com/

Comment: Awesome. I appreciate the time you put into it. Thanks